# google static maps api returns blue image

Tags: google-maps

I try to get the satellite example to work:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/

The url for the request is (with the correct API key...):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=satellite¢er=37.530101,38.600062&zoom=14&size=640x400&key=API_KEY
```

This is the result:

[image]

Where the expected result is:

[image]

I checked the coordinates: 37.530101,38.600062 with google earth and they should bring me to the expected result.

If I look in the google developer console then I can see the requests are made.

If I try this one for example (with the key).

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false&key=
```

Then I do get an image.

Why doesn't the first one work?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

In the url google provides it says:

```
?maptype=satellite¢er=37.530101,38.600062
```

Where

```
¢er
```

Should be:

```
&center
```

I guess someone at google had a hangover.